# How to compare two list<Object1> and List<Object2> in c#

Tags: c#, linq

[grpmembersDlist](https://i.s**)

[grpmembersSlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/412wc.png)

I am trying to compare two list. First list have 93 records. And second list have 1 record. I want to compare these two lists. In first list, first record is same as second list record. So trying to get the remaining 92 records. I have tried this code. Please have a look.

```
var grpmembersDlist = unManagedGroupsRepo.GetGroupMembers(FinalGrpsList, target, concurancyThread);//get group members based on FinalList.
var grpmembersSlist = unManagedGroupsRepo.GetGroupMembersSnapshot(target);//get groupmembers from snapshot table
var FinalgrpmembersList = grpmembersDlist.Where(x => !grpmembersSlist.Contains(x)).ToList();//check this group members in groupsnapshot table. get the list of groupmembers which are not present in groupsnapshot table.
```

In FinalgrpmembersList i'm getting 93 records. This code is not working for me.
Can you please help me. Please check the images for more info.

Comment: Compare them by a unique id, like loginName

Comment: the first link is broken; and frankly, the second is quite meaningless. You can probably show the lists in text; not in image and ask the question better. good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be better implementations such as implementing `IEquatable<T>` in the `GroupMember` class where you can define how you want to define the equality between two members. But to stick with your implementation, you can simply replace the last line

```
var FinalgrpmembersList = grpmembersDlist.Where(x => !grpmembersSlist.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

to

```
var FinalgrpmembersList = grpmembersDlist.Where(x => !grpmembersSlist.Any(m => m.GroupName == x.GroupName && m.LoginName == x.LoginName)).ToList();
```